# php sort function

Tags: php, function, sorting, select

I made a function to sort data but it does not work:

```
public static function images($col,$order,$start, $perpage)
    {
        $query = 'select * from `image` ORDER BY'.$col.$order.'limit '.$start.','.$perpage;
        $items = DbHandler::GetAll($query);
        return $items;
    }
```

I also tried this:

```
public static function images($col,$order,$start, $perpage)
    {
        $query = 'select * from `image` ORDER BY :col :order limit :start,:perpage';
        $params = array(':col'=>$col ,':order'=>$order,':start'=>$start , ':perpage'=>$perpage);
        $items = DbHandler::GetAll($query,$params);
        return $items;
    }
```

None of those functions work. Help me out of here, please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: would you post the output ?

Comment: I think you meant SQL sort, instead of PHP sort ?

Comment: you can't bind `limit` and `offset`, maybe that is the problem

Comment: I think you need some spaces here :  BY'.$col.$order.'limit

Comment: Please add a description of your error to your question.

Comment: @Hossam empty array ...    Array ()

Comment: @ventiseis no error .. te output is empty array